# MSIL code problem

Tags: .net, cil

I am trying to modificate an assembly (mine) just by ildassembling it and by modifying the MSIL code.
I just want to pop a MessageBox.

Here is my code :

`.module extern Fusion.dll`

`.module extern kernel32.dll`

`.module extern advapi32.dll`

`.module extern aspnet_state.exe`

`.module extern webengine.dll`

`.module extern aspnet_wp.exe`

`.module extern mscorwks.dll`

`.module extern ole32.dll`

`.module extern mscoree.dll`

`.module extern Netapi32.dll`

`.assembly extern mscorlib`

`{`

`...`

`...`

`IL_0052:  ldstr "ahahahahahah"`

`IL_0057:  callvirt instance [mscorlib]System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox::Show(string)`

`IL_005c:  ldloc.0`

`IL_005d:  ret`

`} // end of method`

`...`

I have no error, but the MessageBox does not appear :\

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 6):

should be

```
  ldstr "ahahahahahah"
  call valuetype [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult[System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox::Show(string)
  pop
  ret
```

btw, `MessageBox` should not work in web app, because it interacts with desktop user

what is wrong with your code:

```
callvirt instance [mscorlib]System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox::Show(string)
```

1. Show is static method. So it should be called a) with `call` b) without `instance`
2. MessageBox is in `System.Windows.Forms`, not in `mscorlib`
3. You should specify result type, it is actually DialogResult
4. You should `pop` result because you don't need it

Comment: No :(  I precise that it's a web .net application (file.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well MessageBox is a windows form function in System.Windows.Forms.dll so you'd need to add an extern for that and removes the call[mscorlib] bit ...but I don't think it's going to help.

How is an ASPX page is going to generate a Winforms Message box ?
The only thing you could possibly do is emit a Javascript 'alert(message)' to get a web-page style message box, but that's not going to be easily done by modifying MSIL.

Perhaps you should add something like:

```
call void [System]System.Diagnostics.Trace::Write(string)
```

By decompiling a quick console app, this is how the message box call would work:

```
ldstr "blah"
stloc.0 
ldloc.0 
call valuetype [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult [System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox::Show(string)
pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for helping, it's more clear now.

Well, if it's not possible to throw a MessageBox from a aspx file, I have tried to write something in a file.

```
IL_0034:  ldstr      "C:\\...\\WebSite1\\toto.txt"
IL_0039:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.StreamWriter::.ctor(string)
IL_003e:  stloc.1
IL_003f:  ldloc.1
IL_0040:  ldstr      "hello world"
IL_0045:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter::WriteLine(string)
IL_004a:  nop
IL_004b:  ldloc.1
IL_004c:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter::Close()
IL_0051:  nop
```

I have no error or exception when I load the web page, but the file is not created or modified :\

I dont see why because If I put the same code in C# directly in the .aspx, that works fine !